# How does .indexOn works with users and unique keys?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security, pyrebase

I am confused with index rules in firebase. I have this database and I wanted to extract `distance_traveled` in `battery_and_cables`. The thing is, `1` is something like a userID set by the user itself so that will vary.

I used this code in pyrebase to extract the `distance_traveled`

```
db.child("mileage_maintenance").order_by_child("distance_traveled").get()
```

but I get

> Index not defined, add ".indexOn": "distance_traveled", for path "/mileage_maintenance", to the rules

This is my database:

[image: This is my database]

Any my rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
    "mileage_maintenance": {
      "battery_and_cables":{
        ".indexOn": ["distance_traveled"]
       }
    },
  }
}
```

Is there any way you can go through the `1` and the `push` key to acquire the `distance_traveled`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase Realtime Database **queries work on a flat list of the nodes under the location where you run the query**. So in your case, the query considers the direct children of the `mileage_maintenance` node (which is just the node `1` in the screenshot).

You can have wildcards in your rules, like in your case:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
    "mileage_maintenance": {
      "$id": {
        "battery_and_cables":{
          ".indexOn": ["distance_traveled"]
         }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, I added a `$id` level here for the `1` node. That now means that you have an index defined on each `/mileage_maintenance/$id/battery_and_cables` node for the `distance_traveled` property of each child node under that.

So with this index, you can query a specific `/mileage_maintenance/$id/battery_and_cables` path for the `distance_traveled` values. But you can't run a query on just `/mileage_maintenance` for all `distance_traveled` values under it.

If you need such a query, you will need to modify/augment your data model to allow it. For example, by introducing a flat list of `distance_traveled` nodes that you can then query:

```
"distance_traveled": {
   "1000000": "1/battery_and_cables/-M01CT...1hMj"
}
```

Or

```
"distance_traveled": {
   "1~battery_and_cables~-M01CT...1hMj": 1000000
}
```

Where the `~` in that last model is just a separate for the segments in that key, since `/` isn't allowed.

Also see:

- [Firebase Query Double Nested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207059/firebase-query-double-nested)
- [Firebase query if child of child contains a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value)

Comment: Thank you! I now understand more about how indexing works. My problem now is how to call it out in pyrebase since `"error" : "Invalid path: Invalid token in path"` shows up when typing `/mileage_maintenance/$id/battery_and_cables`. Or am I understanding it wrong?

Comment: That sounds like you're trying to use `/` in the **key**, which is not allowed. That's why my last JSON snippet uses `~` as a separator.